# Symfony and Twig: conditions in templates

Tags: php, templates, twig, symfony

I have two bundles I created by my own: one to generate admin sections (`AdminBundle`), and another one to create bills (`BillingBundle`). `BillingBundle` has basically 2 entities: `Client` and `Bill` (1:m).

If I install both bundles to generate the new/edit forms and lists for `Client` and `Bill` at the admin, I include a part at `config.yml` like this:

```
my_admin_bundle:
    entities: 
        project:  #whatever entity. Project at AppBundle for example
            new: true
            list: true
        client:
            new: true
            list: true
        bill:
            new: true
            list: true
```

On the other hand, on `AdminBundle` I have a template called `form.html.twig` which renders the form to create new elements. Basically it is just like this:

```
{{ form(form) }}
```

The doubt: since the form to create new `Bills` need a `.js` file (`accounting.js`), *how to include it only for new `Bill` form but not for new `Client` or `Project` forms ?*

As you can imagine, now I have this in `form.html.twig`:

```
{{ form(form) }}
<script src="/bundles/ziiwebbilling/js/accounting.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

but I **don't** need `accounting.js` at `form.html.twig` for new `Projects`, or new `Clients` forms.

**NOTE**: sorry if I extend too much with my explanation, but I don't know how to explain it in another way. Even the title of the question is awful, please edit it if you find something better.

**EDIT**: as I've just wrote at the first comment for jkucharovic's answer, what I'm really looking for to solve my problem, is a **non-intrusive** way, that is: I wouldn't like to add the line about `accounting.js` inside an `AdminBundle` template. Or maybe am I looking for "too much"?

Comment: Why you just not pass additional variable to template from controller, and make `is defined` statement in twig.

Comment: @malcolm but the controller is the same for all also. There is only one controller.

Comment: And you cannot recognize in that controller instance of class for which form be rendered?

Comment: @malcom yes, but in that case I should override the controller, and I dont' want to change the controller everytime I install BillingBundle.

Comment: You can pass class name as parameter from options, or write Twig custom fuction or test to check instance of entity.

Answer (score 3):

Use [custom Twig extenstion](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html) with test function like this one:

```
public function getTests()
{
    return [
        new \Twig_SimpleTest('bill', function ($var) {
            return $var instanceof Bill;
        })
    ];
}
```

And then in template, you can simply test if form is for `Bill` entity:

```
{{ form(form) }}
{% if form.vars.value is bill %}
<script src="/bundles/ziiwebbilling/js/accounting.js"></script>
{% endif %}
```

**Edit**: If you don't want to modify template inside bundle for certain reason, you can make [loading application-wide](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#making-application-wide-customizations) by defining own template and overriding default `form block`:

```
{%- block form -%}
    {% if form.vars.value is bill %}
    <script src="/bundles/ziiwebbilling/js/accounting.js"></script>
    {% endif %}
    {{ form_start(form) }}
        {{- form_widget(form) -}}
    {{ form_end(form) }}
{%- endblock form -%}
```

Comment: thanks, I still don't know exactly how the Twig extension should be, and why I should need obbligatory a test function. Maybe you can help me a bit more. On the other hand, what I'm really looking for, is a non-intrusive way, that is: I wouldn't like to add the line about accounting.js inside an `AdminBundle` template. Sorry, if I'm expecting too much..:/